# AmazonS3ClientBuilder not picking up access and secret key from application properties in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm trying to configure an S3 client in spring boot.

```
this.s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
            .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .build();
  }
```

Because I'm using a jar, I can't really provide environment variables. Hence, I want to use `SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider()` to get the credentials.

In my application.properties file, I'm passing the keys `aws.accessKeyId=` and `aws.secretAccessKey=` as mentioned in the documentation.

The upload function returns an error saying the credentials are wrong.

Exception:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;
```

EDIT:
You can check in the image that access key and secret key is being taken as null.

[image]

I've passed the keys as `aws.accessKeyId=` and `aws.secretKey=`

Comment: Is it not picking or you provided the incorrect one?

Comment: I'm sure the credentials are right, they're working fine with my other applications

Comment: Is it possible that the application.properties file is not being read?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html mentions `aws.secretKey` (not secretAccessKey)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the AWS Java SDK v1 which expects the secret key to be in a system property called `aws.secretKey`. `aws.secretAccessKey` is the name of the system property if you're using the AWS Java SDK v2.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/migration-client-credentials.html